# is dst a special environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, openwrt, uclibc

I am trying to build code under OpenWRT.  I find that the uClibc compilation breaks [fails to build saying linux/errno.h is not found] if I have an environment variable [defined as export dst=/projects//... on a network-share].

If I change the name of that environment variable [to pkdst] - I do not see that error and OpenWRT build succeeds.

Is $dst some kind of "special" shell-variable under BASH?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I should have mentioned in my post that I had already looked at that page.  I also looked on google and in the BASH documentation on my system and online.
It appears that $dst might be used "internally" by OpenWRT during compile --- since it breaks the toolchain compile of uClibc.  This is what I am trying to confirm.